# Redirect in Laravel .htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.
I make new website (old website was delete)

I have .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.pl/$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect to non www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.pl$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Fonts
    # Add correct content-type for fonts
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
    AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 month"

    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"

</IfModule>
```

This work fine.

I need add to this .htaccess:

1. Redirect from https://domain.pl/oferta (error 404 - page not exist in new website) to https://domain.pl/oferta-2020 , https://domain.pl/kontakt to https://domain.pl/contact
2. Redirect other error 404 to main page: https://domain.pl

How can I make it?

Comment: i think this you can handel by laravel route

Comment: better for me is .htaccess. It's possible?

Comment: i think better will be laravel end becouse then you can add logic also , if you want to  redirect from .htaccess check out this https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in web.php

```php
Route::get('oferta', function () {
    return redirect('oferta-2020');
});
Route::get('kontakt', function () {
    return redirect('contact');
});
Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return redirect('/');}
)->where('all', '(.*)');
```

in laravel end you can redirect this

Comment: It's not working. I have old url: domena.pl/pl/godziny-plywania - new url is domena.pl/plywalnia-godziny. I maje this code: Route::get('pl/godziny-plywania', function () {
    return redirect()->url('plywalnia-godziny');
}); - this return me error Method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::url does not exist.

Comment: I have old URL: domena.pl/pl/zakupy - in new website this url not exist. I have your code in last line web.php: Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return redirect('/');
}); - and this not working. I have error 404

Comment: this work fine: Route::any('{all}', function () {
    return redirect('/');
})->where('all', '(.*)');

Comment: But this return error: Route::get('pl/godziny-plywania', function () {
    return redirect()->url('plywalnia-godziny');
}); - Method Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::url does not exist.

Comment: @opolopo got it fixed it now check

Answer (score 0):

for 404 page add this route in **web.php**

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    return redirect('/');
});
```